# Loop and check to see if a cell is blank - Not registering that a cell is blank

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my code:

```
For Each Cell In NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
If Cell.Value = 76 Or Cell.Value = 69 Then
    MsgBox Cells(Cell.Row, 8).Value
    If NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, 8).Value = "" Then
            Do Until IsEmpty(NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col).Value)
                If Not NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col).Value = "" Then
                col = col + 1
                End If
            Loop
            NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col) = "Codes 69 or 76 Reported w/ No applicable Bankrupcty Rptd"
    End If
End If
col = 50
Next Cell
```

I've also tried:

```
For Each Cell In NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
If Cell.Value = 76 Or Cell.Value = 69 Then
    MsgBox Cells(Cell.Row, 8).Value
    If IsEmpty(NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, 8).Value) = True Then
            Do Until IsEmpty(NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col).Value)
                If Not NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col).Value = "" Then
                col = col + 1
                End If
            Loop
            NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, col) = "Codes 69 or 76 Reported w/ No applicable Bankrupcty Rptd"
    End If
End If
col = 50
Next Cell
```

Both don't register when `cells(cell.row, 8).value` is indeed "".  Not sure what to do.

Comment: First of all - you should debug your code and find out what's going wrong. There might be totally different error with it and you look for it in the other place.

Comment: It is never recommended to perform a Do While loop until cell = "".  That type of programming is almost always error prone and inefficient compared to alternatives, such as a For Each loop which I can see you are using in your code.  Based on what your Do Loop is actually doing, it looks like you want the first unused column in that row.  Why not use `NewBook.Sheets(1).Cells(Cell.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1`?  As a side note, it is also never recommended to use the exact work `cell` as a variable, since it is already a keyword in VBA.

Comment: Love the suggestions.  Even though the error was resolved you guys went ahead and gave me some pointers.  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

It may have something to do with your `Cell` variable.  It is highly recommended to not use that word as a variable, since it's used in VB.  Also, use `With` to cut down a little on the length:

```
For Each cel In NewBook.Sheets(1).Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
If cel.Value = 76 Or cel.Value = 69 Then
    MsgBox Cells(cel.Row, 8).Value
    With NewBook.Sheets(1)
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(cel.Row, 8).Value) = True Then
            Do Until IsEmpty(.Cells(cel.Row, col).Value)
                If Not .Cells(cel.Row, col).Value = "" Then
                col = col + 1
                End If
            Loop
            .Cells(cel.Row, col) = "Codes 69 or 76 Reported w/ No applicable Bankrupcty Rptd"
    End If
    End With
End If
col = 50
Next cel

End Sub
```

Mainly, try changing your `Cell` variable to just `cel` (or anything you like) and see if it works.  The `With` part is just personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with the original data.  It comes from a CSV file and the cell.value is not "".  It is " ".  Pesky spaces.

Comment: Ah there you go!  But I would note my comment about using `Cell` as a variable...it can get confusing using that variable.